# converting dataframe from one format to another

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am creating a spark structured streaming application and I have a streaming dataframe which has the below data in it.

```
{
"name":"sensor1",
"time":"2020-11-27T01:01:00",
"sensorvalue":11.0,
"tag1":"tagvalue"
}
```

I would like to convert that dataframe into below format.

```
{
"name":"sensor1",
"value-array":
[
{
"time":"2020-11-27T01:01:00",
"sensorvalue":11.0,
"tag1":"tagvalue"
}
]
}
```

I tried using mapPartition() / map() method, where I get a row Object and I tried creating another dataframe in the expected format.

I am able to get the values from row object using row(0) or row(1). But, Is it possible to put a POJO/schema for that row object (Using Row Encoders()) ? That way instead of using row(0), we can use row.getName() ?

```
val mapDF = incomingDF.map(row =>{
    val name = row(0).toString
    /* val name = row.getName */

  })
```

I tried using collect_list() function. Since its an aggregate function, I couldn't use "append" as output mode in my streaming application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array` and `struct` functions.

Check below code.

```
scala> df
.withColumn("value-array",array(struct($"time",$"sensorvalue",$"tag1")))
.select(to_json(struct($"name",$"value-array")).as("json_data"))
```

Above code will give you output like below.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|json_data                                                                                                  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"name":"sensor1","value-array":[{"time":"2020-11-27T01:01:00.000Z","sensorvalue":11.0,"tag1":"tagvalue"}]}|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: When I send the transformed DF to a kafka topic - the json is getting stringified like this - {"name":"sensor1","value-array":[{\"time\":\"2020-11-27T01:01:00.000Z\",\"sensorvalue\":11.0,\"tag1\":\"tagvalue\"}]}|... is it possible to send the json to kafka topic - without those " quotes ??

Comment: Can you post code how you are sending to Kafka as new question ??

Comment: Have posted a new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65101659/sending-json-events-to-kafka-in-non-stringified-format